# Redirect if string found in URL

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-redirect, query-variable

I'm trying to redirect non-logged in users to the login page when viewing any pages relating to a plugin.

My code is working fine when I specify which pages they can't view, but I'm trying to pull in a string from the URL which is where I'm struggling.

Here is an example URL:
http://domain.com/idx/city/irvine/

I am trying to detect the string 'idx' in the URL.
I looked at the rewrite rules defined in the IDX plugin I'm using:

```
"idx/city/([^/]+)(?:/page\-(\\d+))?"       => 'index.php?idx-action=results&idx-q-Cities=$matches[1]&idx-d-ResultPage=$matches[2]'
```

I've tried checking if $_GET['idx-action'] is set but that didn't work.

```
// Check for registered user or redirect to login/register page
add_action('template_redirect','tc_check_if_logged_in');
function tc_check_if_logged_in() {
// If user is not logged in, check for restricted pages (inside array) and ignore home/front page and admin pages
//if (!is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( array('1306','999999','999998',)) && !is_home() && !is_front_page() && !is_admin())) // commented out as I know this part works

if ($_GET['idx-action']) // Check if IDX query set 
{
    // If restricted, redirect to login page then redirect back to original page
    $url = add_query_arg(
        'redirect_to',
        get_permalink(),
        site_url('wp-login.php')
    );
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}   
}
```

Sorry if question is unclear. Got a really bad head cold and can't think!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't just use PHP strpos() to detect it?

Comment: I tried it and it works if there's a page with the term in it (domain.com/idx-test/), but when it's accessing a page generated by the plugin (domain.com/idx/city/irvine/) I just get a white screen (with WP_DEBUG set to true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in `$_GET` will be set for internal rewrite rules, that's not how they work. Look in the query vars for `idx-action`- either `get_query_var('idx-action')` or `$wp_query->query_vars['idx-action']`.